# Allow permission or enable permission

Tags: word-usage, american-english

What is the correct way to ask mobile app user to grant certain permission on their phone in American English:

- please allow permission
- please enable permission
- please grant permission

If none of the above is correct, please suggest the right word.

Comment: @PeterShor — why are you answering in a comment? There is already an answer — albeit unsatisifactory — that disagrees with yours. The correct thing to do is to either 1. write an answer of your own, justifying your choice 2. Comment on the answer you disagree with, or 3. Ignore the question and vote to close if you think it does not belong on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permission: the act of allowing someone to do a particular thing

Hence, grant/give permission is the only right usage here; the other two repeat the meaning of "allowing".

Comment: If you are telling somebody to toggle a permission button in some electronic system, "grant permission" doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @PeterShor.  The use of "grant" is technical terminology.  E.g. in MySQL, one might say `GRANT SELECT ON db.thing TO 'peter'@'localhost';`  A simple "give" is perhaps the best thing to use in *all* situations though.